# How I can get current gmail login

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gmail

I have a web-appl with: Spring MVC 4, Spring Data, Spring Security. How I can get login(email) with which current user sign in Gmail account? I try to get cookies from `HttpServletRequest` but it doesn't store this data.
And I try to get cookie like this:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    //creates URL for the given string
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://www.google.co.in/");
        //open's a connection with the URL specified and returns URLConnection object
        URLConnection  urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        // get's the contents from this URL specifies
        urlConnection.getContent();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //returns the cookie store(bunch of cookies)
    CookieStore cookieStore = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
    //getting cookies which returns in the form of List of type HttpCookie
    List<HttpCookie> listOfcookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
    for(HttpCookie httpCookie: listOfcookies){
        System.out.println("Cookie Name : "+httpCookie.getName()+" Cookie Value : "+httpCookie.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Why would Google cookies be sent to your application? You're not Gmail or any other Google's product, so why should the browser send potentially sensitive information to your app?

Comment: You'll have to look for an API to do things like this. Just google it.

Comment: I have to use Spring Social for it  ?